# Why reading from PTY slave changes line(discipline) settings?

Tags: c, linux, unix, tty, pty

I set a termios ECHO setting on master of `PTY`.
But after reading from `PTY`, it get's switched to non `ECHO` mode.

Example:

When I spawn `bash` and type `stty` I'll get a result which I expect.

```sh
$stty
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

termios flags

```
c_iflag: 1024, c_oflag: 5, c_cflag: 191, c_lflag: 35385, c_line: 0, c_cc: [3, 28, 127, 21, 4, 0, 1, 0, 17, 19, 26, 0, 18, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], c_ispeed: 15, c_ospeed: 15

input_flags: IXON
output_flags: OPOST | ONLCR
control_flags: CS6 | CS7 | CS8 | CREAD | CSIZE
local_flags: ECHOKE | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHO | ECHOCTL | ISIG | IEXTEN
control_chars: [3, 28, 127, 21, 4, 0, 1, 0, 17, 19, 26, 0, 18, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But when we read even 1 byte from `PTY` before sending a command `stty` we will get a different result.
We will get a `^M` character instead of `\n`. And we will get a `ECHO` turned off.

```sh
stty^Mspeed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
-echo
```

termios flags after reading

```
c_iflag: 1024, c_oflag: 5, c_cflag: 191, c_lflag: 35377, c_line: 0, c_cc: [3, 28, 127, 21, 4, 0, 1, 0, 17, 19, 26, 0, 18, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], c_ispeed: 15, c_ospeed: 15

input_flags: IXON
output_flags: OPOST | ONLCR
control_flags: CS6 | CS7 | CS8 | CREAD | CSIZE
local_flags: ECHOKE | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHOCTL | ISIG | IEXTEN
control_chars: [3, 28, 127, 21, 4, 0, 1, 0, 17, 19, 26, 0, 18, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can find related issue on github: https://github.com/zhiburt/expectrl/issues/10

Thank you.

Comment: Bash and other shells may alter the terminal settings before and after showing a prompt

Comment: I guess you're right.
But why it happens exactly when we read something before turning echo mode.

Comment: Well, @ninjalj you may be actually right I verified that if we spawn `CAT` and do read before it's fine wheres with python IDLE and bash it's not